# Count num of occurrences by value in a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, count, histogram, series

I have a Pandas series like the following one:

```
    id    val
    id_1   1
    id_2   1
    id_3   2
    id_4   2
    id_5   1
    ...
```

I want to count the number of `ids` with value `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. Something like this:

```
    value n_ocurr 
    1     102
    2     20
    3     40 
    ...
```

Is there an easy way to do this? (hopefully without converting the series to a `pd.DataFrame`)

Comment: Use the `.value_counts()`?

Comment: @Psidom sorry i was misspelling it, it worked !

Comment: `df.val.value_counts()` should work.